# Nuget not copying content

Tags: deployment, nuget, nuspec

I am having a problem including a file i need in order for the project to work, here is the nuspec file that i have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>package_name</id>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <title>x Wrapper</title>
        <authors>me</authors>
        <owners>me</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>package desc.</description>
        <releaseNotes>Bugfix to exe not being copied.</releaseNotes>
        <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
        <tags></tags>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="x.Common.Interfaces" version="1.0.0" />
            <dependency id="x.Common.Logging" version="1.0.0" />
            <dependency id="x.Wrapper.Common" version="1.0.0" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="build\package_name.props" target="build\package_name.props" />
        <file src="build\package_name.targets" target="build\package_name.targets" />
        <file src="x.Wrapper\x.exe" target="content\x.exe" />
        <file src="bin\Debug\package_name.dll" target="lib\net45\package_name.dll" />
    </files>
</package>
```

When package is pushed and installed to nuget server there is only project dll + dependencies dll's but no other files are being copied into the project. Anyone with some more experience with nuget packages has idea on what could be going on ?

Comment: Just figured it out, i was deleting and adding the package under the same version. For some reason server was serving the first version whole time. In the end, this file is totally legit, as long as the props/targets is correct.